# Javascript object literal inside object literal

Tags: javascript, oop, object

In the following JavaScript example, are we seeing 2 object literals  as properties of an object literal?

```
dw_Tooltip.content_vars = {
link1: {
    img: 'images/dw-btn.gif',
    txt: 'dyn-web button',
    w: 100
},
link2: {
    img: 'images/dot-com-btn.gif',
    txt: 'dyn-web.com button',
    w: 184
}
```

}

Comment: What would be an alternative interpretation? (No snark intended).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

link1 and link2 are properties of the content_vars object.
However, link1 and link2 are objects, themselves, with their own properties.

You can nest an infinite number of objects or arrays inside of other objects or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is perfectly valid. You can nest object liberals like this as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a object `dw_Tooltip` having a property `content_vars` that is an object that has 2 objects, `link1` and `link2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are. `link1` and `link2` are object literals which are properties of the `content_var` object literal.